# Seleccionar una opcion en un combobox y no poder volver a seleccionarla en el siguiente

Tags: python, django

Estoy con el proyecto final de carrera, y estoy atrancado en uno de mis formularios. Tengo 4 combobox con distintas opciones para seleccionar. Lo que busco es que, si en un combobox selecciono una de las opciones, ésta no pueda ser seleccionada en ninguno de los demás, para así evitar repeticiones de la misma opción.

Preguntad lo que queráis si necesitáis que os resuelva alguna duda más, o alguna parte de código exacta.

Mi models.py

```
nota_35='35'
nota_36='36'
nota_37='37'
nota_38='38'
nota_39='39'
nota_40='40'
nota_41='41'
nota_42='42'
nota_43='43'
nota_44='44'
nota_45='45'
nota_46='46'
nota_47='47'
nota_48='48'
nota_49='49'
nota_50='50'
nota_51='51'
nota_52='52'
nota_53='53'
nota_54='54'
nota_55='55'
nota_56='56'
nota_57='57'
nota_58='58'
nota_59='59'
nota_60='60'
nota_61='61'
nota_62='62'
nota_63='63'
nota_64='64'
nota_65='65'
nota_66='66'
nota_67='67'
nota_68='68'
nota_69='69'
nota_70='70'
nota_71='71'
nota_72='72'
nota_73='73'
nota_74='74'
nota_75='75'
nota_76='76'
nota_77='77'
nota_78='78'
nota_79='79'
nota_80='80'
nota_81='81'

notas=((nota_35,'Acoustic Bass Drum'),(nota_36,'Bass Drum 1'),(nota_37,'Side Stick'),(nota_38,'Acoustic Snare'),(nota_39,'Hand Clap'),
(nota_40,'Electric Snare'),(nota_41,'Low Floor Tom'),(nota_42,'Closed Hi Hat'),(nota_43,'High Floor Tom'),(nota_44,'Pedal Hi-Hat'),
(nota_45,'Low Tom'),(nota_46,'Open Hi-Hat'),(nota_47,'Low-Mid Tom'),(nota_48,'Hi-Mid Tom'),(nota_49,'Crash Cymbal 1'),(nota_50,'High Tom'),
(nota_51,'Ride Cymbal 1'),(nota_52,'Chinese Cymbal'),(nota_53,'Ride Bell'),(nota_54,'Tambourine'),(nota_55,'Splash Cymbal'),
(nota_56,'Cowbell'),(nota_57,'Crash Cymbal 2'),(nota_58,'Vibraslap'),(nota_59,'Ride Cymbal 2'),(nota_60,'Hi Bongo'),(nota_61,'Low Bongo'),
(nota_62,'Mute Hi Conga'),(nota_63,'Open Hi Conga'),(nota_64,'Low Conga'),(nota_65,'High Timbale'),(nota_66,'Low Timbale'),(nota_67,'High Agogo'),
(nota_68,'Low Agogo'),(nota_69,'Cabasa'),(nota_70,'Maracas'),(nota_71,'Short Whistle'),(nota_72,'Long Whistle'),(nota_73,'Short Guiro'),
(nota_74,'Long Guiro'),(nota_75,'Claves'),(nota_76,'Hi Wood Block'),(nota_77,'Low Wood Block'),(nota_78,'Mute Cuica'),(nota_79,'Open Cuica'),
(nota_80,'Mute Triangle'),(nota_81,'Open Triangle'))

nota_pad_verde=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=notas, default=notas[0][0])
nota_pad_gris=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=notas, default=notas[0][0])
nota_pad_azul=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=notas, default=notas[0][0])
nota_pad_amarillo=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=notas, default=notas[0][0])
nota_pad_rojo=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=notas, default=notas[0][0])
```

Mi forms.py

```
class FormCancion(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cancion
        fields= ['nota_pad_verde','nota_pad_gris','nota_pad_azul','nota_pad_amarillo','nota_pad_rojo']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormCancion, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['nota_pad_verde'].widget.attrs.update({'required':'','data-html':'true','title':'Instrumento que se desea asignar al pad verde','data-toggle':'tooltip', 'data-placement':'right'})
        self.fields['nota_pad_gris'].widget.attrs.update({'required':'','data-html':'true','title':'Instrumento que se desea asignar al pad gris','data-toggle':'tooltip', 'data-placement':'right'})
        self.fields['nota_pad_azul'].widget.attrs.update({'required':'','data-html':'true','title':'Instrumento que se desea asignar al pad azul','data-toggle':'tooltip', 'data-placement':'right'})
        self.fields['nota_pad_amarillo'].widget.attrs.update({'required':'','data-html':'true','title':'Instrumento que se desea asignar al pad amarillo', 'data-toggle':'tooltip', 'data-placement':'right'})
        self.fields['nota_pad_rojo'].widget.attrs.update({'required':'','data-html':'true','title':'Instrumento que se desea asignar al pad rojo','data-toggle':'tooltip', 'data-placement':'right'})
```

Comment: te sugiero usar algo de jquery .javascript....en el evento onchange de tu select agrega..o manda a llamar una funcion que valide la seleccion de cada uno..que no se repitan entre si..!!

Comment: Podrias orientarme más o menos como debería hacer eso? Ando un poco perdido en Javascript y no sabría exactamente como hacerlo

Comment: si claro ya posteo una posible solucion..!!

Comment: Tengo una duda, a ver si me la pudieses resolver. En el campo del select, las opciones que a mi me gustaría introducir las tengo en un modelo como choices, y no se como acoplarlo al formulario de html que me indicaste. ¿Podrías ayudarme a solucionar esto? @Tegito123

Comment: espero esto te ayude: https://justpaste.it/4dcby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada deberiamos tener nuestros select: algo asi:

```
<form id="myform">
<label for="nota1">Nota1:</label>
<select id="nota_1" onchange="validar();">
<option selected disable>Seleccione</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="nota2">Nota2:</label>
<select id="nota_2" onchange="validar();">
<option selected disable>Seleccione</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
</form>
```

en este caso el select puedes hacerlo desde un form de django y con los atributos o widgets adicionas el evento onchange que yo uso para llamar a una funcion que valide la seleccion de cada select.

```
function validar(){

  var select1 = $("#nota_1").val();
  var select2 = $("#nota_2").val();
  if (select1 ==select2 ){
    alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
    //reset form
    document.getElementById('myform').reset();
  }
    return false;
}//end function validar
```

lo que hago en esta funcion es primero obtener los valores de cada select mediante su id, esto lo puedes hacer por id, clase..etc.. y luego valido si son iguales y mando hacer un alert..algo basico y aplico un reset al form..ya depende tu logica o lo que deseas hacer.. pero es un ejemplo basico y espero te sirva de guia.!!

**codigo completo:**

```
<form id="myform">
<label for="nota1">Nota1:</label>
<select id="nota_1" onchange="validar();">
<option selected disable>Seleccione</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="nota2">Nota2:</label>
<select id="nota_2" onchange="validar();">
<option selected disable>Seleccione</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
</form>
<script>
function validar(){

  var select1 = $("#nota_1").val();
  var select2 = $("#nota_2").val();
  if (select1 ==select2 ){
    alert("Seleccione valores distintos !!");
    //reset form
    document.getElementById('myform').reset();
  }
    return false;
}//end function validar
</script>
```